# Cleanest way to check if a key exists on an embedded hash inside an embedded array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out a good way to find whether or not an `error_body` is present on the `resq` in this hash.

```
hash_v = {"brand"=>[{ "model_id"=>["1"], "resq"=>[{"error_body"=>[{"message"=>["Error"]}]}]}]}
```

This is the cleanest way that I've seen so far, but I'm wondering if there's a better way, perhaps by using `dig`, to make this a bit cleaner.

```
hash_v['brand'].map { |m| m['resq'].first['error_body'] }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened when you tried using `dig`? Can you guarantee the "resq" array will always be in that order?

Comment: Yes, I can. `dig` doesn't seem to play well with embedded hashes with arrays... I couldn't figure out the correct format.

Comment: Any suggestions? @theTinMan

Comment: If you know it's always in that order, then `hash_v['brand'].first['resq'].first['error_body'] # => [{"message"=>["Error"]}]`. `map` is the wrong tool for this. The data structure isn't very clean. Every hash value is an array containing something else. If you're generating it I'd recommend rethinking it as it's not clean.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if using `dig` is the cleanest way to check if a key exists on an embedded hashes with arrays, but this solution may work :

```
 hash_v.dig("brand", 0, "resq", 0, "error_body")
```

Comment: Show how it works. Hint: `hash_v.keys.include?("error_body") # => false`

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry, i misunderstood the question

Comment: Converting to a string could yield false positives if `to_s["error_body"]` matched on a sub-string. You could use `/\berror_body\b/` to match whole-words... but it could also then match inside a string value that happened to exist somewhere else in the hash. There are ifs to all that, but determining whether the key exists needs to be accurate. `dig` is probably a better idea as long as the order of the hashes and arrays are consistent.